# Do people still play Gears of War online on PC?

Tags: pc, games-for-windows-live, gears-of-war

I've had an overwhelming urge to replay *Gears of War* recently, specifically on PC, which I have never done before.

Before I purchase the game, I'm curious - does anyone still play *Gears of War* multiplayer on PC?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the Tour regarding if this kind of question is On or Off topic - I will delete it if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Games For Windows Was going to become [defunct](http://www.polygon.com/2013/8/19/4637694/microsoft-games-for-windows-live-service-ending-july-2014) but later after 2014's E3 Gamespot reported to the contratary [as seen here](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/microsoft-says-it-s-not-shutting-down-games-for-windows-live/1100-6420654/).

The community is low, there is [little in way of support for the title](https://forums.epicgames.com/forums/360-Gears-of-War-for-Windows). If you CAN get the updates installed there *may* be a few players but somewhere in lower to middle hundreds, nothing like it was in its heyday.

Comment: Gutting. Nothing has ever quite replicated the great sense of competition that *Gears of War* did in it's glory years.

Comment: [Looks like my craving for Gears of War on PC may be satisfied anyway](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQqQIwAGoVChMIsOPUrrCWxgIVUFnbCh1IfwD_&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eurogamer.net%2Farticles%2F2015-06-17-gears-of-war-ultimate-edition-is-coming-to-pc&ei=2ziBVfCJJtCy7QbI_oH4Dw&usg=AFQjCNEDe0cWgt0DJUtRfoKGP4Dz5kpg3w&bvm=bv.96041959,d.ZGU).

Comment: Nothing like a revival.